# Does RFC 9110 effectively obsolete RFC 1945?

Tags: http, rfc

Although I'm aware that [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc1945) is categorized as informational - and therefore is not in the standards track, it seems that [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc9110) would effectively obsolete RFC 1945 if the latter was an internet standard.

In other words, why would someone that already read RFC 9110 and is not interested in the history of the internet need to read RFC 1945?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/

Comment: Semantically it makes no sense for a standards document to obsolete an informational document.  Any reasonable reader would in any event observe the last maintenance dates and regard a document from 1997 to be "historic".

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're correct that if RFC 1945 had been a Standard, RFC 9110 would have obsoleted it. That said, HTTP/1.0 (1945) was not a standards-track document. As an informational spec, it was describing a protocol that already existed, over which the IETF did not have change control. To the extent that protocol still exists, RFC 1945 still accurately describes it.

HTTP/1.1 *is* under the control of the IETF, and RFC 9112 is the most recent iteration of that specification, which is decidedly still in use.